# ¿Cómo hacer que, al usar el comando de aleatoridad, pare luego de una cierta cifra?

Tags: processing

```
void setup()
{
  background (0,0,0); 
  size (500,500);
}
void draw ()
{  
 
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  
}
void drawRect ( float w,float e, float q )
{
 fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  rect (w,e,q,q*2);
}
```

Este es mi código y lo que trato de lograr es que luego de dibujar unos cuantos cuadrados o rectángulos este pare de hacerlo. Hasta ahora este dibuja cuadrados o rectángulos sin parar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la función draw se ejecuta cada cuadro. Es decir, si el `display` de tu computadora va a 60 cuadros por segundo, la función `draw` se ejecutará 60 veces en un segundo.

Por lo tanto, cada vez que se llama la función `draw`, un nuevo cuadro es dibujado.

Una solución a tu problema es que tengas una propiedad en tu clase de tipo `bool` como `didDrawSquares`.

Este es el ejemplo hecho en `processing.js` pero debería ser suficiente para entender como hacer el `draw` de los rectángulos que necesites una sola vez.

```
let didDrawSquares = false;

function setup() {
  background (0,0,0);
}

function draw() {
  // Si ya dibujamos una vez los cuadros, no hay necesidad de ejecutar 
  // el resto del código de draw
  if (didDrawSquares)
    return;
    
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  drawRect (random (400),random (450),random (50));
  didDrawSquares = true;
}

function drawRect(w, q, e) {
  fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  rect (w , e, q, q*2);
}
```